# Can a creature that has been Reincarnated be Resurrected using the old body?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, resurrection, reincarnation

Say a creature (humanoid) was killed and then reincarnated through the *Reincarnate* spell, gaining a new body. (Note that *Reincarnate* does not destroy the old body). Then that creature is killed again.

Can that creature be brought back to life through a *Resurrection* spell using the creature's old body? And would it resurrect in the old body or the body from *Reincarnate*?

Comment: Possible addition I've thought of: "If the flesh component of the Clone spell is from the original body of a reincarnated creature is the original body grown?"

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would rule that this would work, but only if the body from *[Reincarnate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate)* (PHB page 271) is destroyed such that it can't be used for *[Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resurrection)* (PHB page 272), leaving the initial body the only remaining body.

Also, the initial body would still be subject to all the rules of *Resurrection*:

- that the creature has to have been dead for no more than a century,
- that it didn't die of old age,
- and that the original body isn't an undead.

The further effect that only happens when the creature has been dead for more than a year should also apply using the original death date and not the death date post-Reincarnate.

Comment: Can you support your ruling by explaining your reasoning for why you would rule on this interaction in this way? (Also, have you encountered this situation in practice and ruled in this way?)